# smoothDivScroll fails if run within the .load() event handler

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

[smoothDivScroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/) 1.3 fails for me if called within `$(window).load()`. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kCfe/).

The .load() event handler is deprecated so I tried to use the [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) jQuery plugin like so:

```
(function ($) { if($('.scroller').length)
    $('.scroller').imagesLoaded(function() {
        $('.scroller').smoothDivScroll({});
    });
})(jQuery);
```

but that too fails in Safari, Chrome and Opera. No errors are displayed in the console of those browsers. It works in Firefox though. Browser versions are up to date.

Any ideas why this fails?

Comment: Why do you need to call it inside the load event? I just tried it without the load and it works nice (the smoothScroll). Whats the point?

Comment: It's to have the callback function run after all images have fully loaded. Although .load() is somewhat [inconsistent](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) in that regard. I think it doesn't run before [DOM is fully loaded](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), but may run later. That is also the reason I tried with the imagesLoaded plugin.

Comment: Does the fiddle work? It is set to use onDomReady, so have you tried $(document).ready?

Comment: @iGanja smoothDivScroll does work with `$(document).ready()` but my question is about using `.load()`.

Comment: I guess I am missing something then. jQuery generally recommends using $(document).ready() in most cases, so if it works, I am confused why we must use .load()?

Comment: @seron I have the exact same question: why do you need the load event?? jQuery says its deprecated. This means you shouldnt use it (no matter if using smoothscroll or not). Why do you need it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you pasted fails because the `.scroller` is not necessarily loaded when you execute that function, thus returning a `length` of 0. Just put it inside a `$(document).ready` handler. Or short:

```
$(function() {
    $('.scroller').smoothDivScroll({});
});
```

JSFiddle adds that for you, but in your scripts you need to wrap code that depends on DOM elements into a function like this.